# How to get all macro name from string using javascript?

Tags: javascript

Given the string below, I tried to get every macro name without '()'.

```
data = `{% macro exportButtonLink() %}
        <div id="exportButton">
            <button type="button">Export</button>
        </div>
    {% endmacro %}

    {% macro submitButton() %}
        <div id="submitButton">
            <button type="button">submitButton</button>
        </div>
    {% endmacro %}

    {% macro ResetButton() %}
        <div id="ResetButton">
            <button type="button">ResetButton</button>
        </div>
    {% endmacro %}`;
```

It would be resulted in `exportButtonLink`,`submitButton`, and `ResetButton`.

I tried testing to loop every character of it if it meet the word I need, but I don't know how to get it out. Thanks.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    console.log(data.charAt(i));
}
```

Comment: are you using `CMake`? I don't know this syntax and macro handling

Comment: @messerbill, macro here is string stored in a text file, so after I read a text file it return a string as above, and I want to extract those macro name from that string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm making a guess based on your data that a macro will always follow the word "marco", and always include a set of parentheses at the end. If so, you can use a regex with the `g` flag to find all the matches.

The regex `.exec` method can be called multiple times to give each match found. You can use it as the condition of a loop to get each match until there are no more matches (and the macro name would be the first capture group of each match):

```js
data = `{% macro exportButtonLink() %}
        <div id="exportButton">
            <button type="button">Export</button>
        </div>
    {% endmacro %}

    {% macro submitButton() %}
        <div id="submitButton">
            <button type="button">submitButton</button>
        </div>
    {% endmacro %}

    {% macro ResetButton() %}
        <div id="ResetButton">
            <button type="button">ResetButton</button>
        </div>
    {% endmacro %}`;
    
const rgx = /macro (\w+)\(/g;
let m;
while (m = rgx.exec(data)) {
    console.log(m[1])
}
```

Comment: yeah, it's correct, that I am trying achieve, thanks very much.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a regex that  ensures that the text is enclosed in the required delimiters.

```
/{%\s+macro\s+([^(]+)\(\)\s+%}/g;
```

Use this in a loop with the `.exec()` method to extract the results.

***Click for demo:***

```js
var re = /{%\s+macro\s+([^(]+)\(\)\s+%}/g;
var data = `{% macro exportButtonLink() %}
        <div id="exportButton">
            <button type="button">Export</button>
        </div>
    {% endmacro %}

    {% macro submitButton() %}
        <div id="submitButton">
            <button type="button">submitButton</button>
        </div>
    {% endmacro %}

    {% macro ResetButton() %}
        <div id="ResetButton">
            <button type="button">ResetButton</button>
        </div>
    {% endmacro %}`;
    
var result = [];
var match = null;
while ((match=re.exec(data))) {
  result.push(match[1]);
}

console.log(result);
```

---

You can also use the callback feature of `.replace()` to gather the results.

***Click for demo:***

```js
var re = /{%\s+macro\s+([^(]+)\(\)\s+%}/g;
var data = `{% macro exportButtonLink() %}
        <div id="exportButton">
            <button type="button">Export</button>
        </div>
    {% endmacro %}

    {% macro submitButton() %}
        <div id="submitButton">
            <button type="button">submitButton</button>
        </div>
    {% endmacro %}

    {% macro ResetButton() %}
        <div id="ResetButton">
            <button type="button">ResetButton</button>
        </div>
    {% endmacro %}`;
    
var result = [];
data.replace(re, (m, g1) => result.push(g1));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

use a regular expression:

```js
data = `{% macro exportButtonLink() %}
        <div id="exportButton">
            <button type="button">Export</button>
        </div>
    {% endmacro %}

    {% macro submitButton() %}
        <div id="submitButton">
            <button type="button">submitButton</button>
        </div>
    {% endmacro %}

    {% macro ResetButton() %}
        <div id="ResetButton">
            <button type="button">ResetButton</button>
        </div>
    {% endmacro %}`;
  
macros = data.match(/macro \w+/g);
console.log(macros);
```

Answer (score 0):

Non-regex based solution with some simple string and array operations with assumptions made based on sample data.

`split` `map` `trim` `split` `slice` `filter`

```js
let data = `{% macro exportButtonLink() %}
        <div id="exportButton">
            <button type="button">Export</button>
        </div>
    {% endmacro %}

    {% macro submitButton() %}
        <div id="submitButton">
            <button type="button">submitButton</button>
        </div>
    {% endmacro %}

    {% macro ResetButton() %}
        <div id="ResetButton">
            <button type="button">ResetButton</button>
        </div>
    {% endmacro %}`;
    
console.log(data.split("\n").map(function (line) {
    if (line.indexOf("{% macro ") > -1) {
      return line.trim().split(" ")[2].slice(0, -2);
    }
}).filter(Boolean))
```